Python - Join Objects into a new, empty Object using Geometry Nodes
So I have this code from another question. It takes all the selected objects and creates a geometry nodes set up on the Active object that joins them all together.
import bpy

# Create a new Geometry Nodes tree
nt = bpy.data.node_groups.new(name='NewGeometryNodesTree', type='GeometryNodeTree')

# Retrieve active object
active_object = bpy.context.active_object

# Create Geometry Nodes modifier on the active object
modifier = active_object.modifiers.new(name="Geometry Nodes", type='NODES')
modifier.node_group = nt

# Access the node tree within the modifier
nodes = modifier.node_group.nodes
links = modifier.node_group.links

#Create group output
group_output = nodes.new('NodeGroupOutput')
group_output.location.x = 600

# Add a Geometry output to the Group Output node
nt.outputs.new('NodeSocketGeometry', 'Geometry')


#Create group input
group_input = nodes.new('NodeGroupInput')
group_input.location.x = -500

# Add a Geometry input to the Group input node
nt.inputs.new('NodeSocketGeometry', 'Geometry')

# Create nodes and set up the node tree
join_geo = nodes.new('GeometryNodeJoinGeometry')
join_geo.location.x = 300
for i, ob in enumerate(bpy.context.selected_objects):
    if ob == active_object:
        continue
    node = nodes.new('GeometryNodeObjectInfo')
    node.location = (-170 * (i % 2), i * 100)
    node.inputs['Object'].default_value = ob
    #Comment next line to have them set to Original Instead
    node.transform_space = 'RELATIVE'
    links.new(node.outputs['Geometry'], join_geo.inputs['Geometry'])
    
   
links.new(join_geo.outputs['Geometry'], group_output.inputs['Geometry'])

#Commenting the last line prevents the original geometry from being included
links.new(group_input.outputs['Geometry'], join_geo.inputs['Geometry'])

What I want it to do instead is create a new object and add the geometry nodes tree to it, ignoring it's own mesh.
Spawning a cube is easy enough but I don't know how to make the code save the object/objects that were selected before so it can go back to them and use the loop.
Is there a way to do that?
To illustrate this is what I tart with (1 or more selected objects)

And this is what I want to get:

A new object, cube or whatever, doesn't matter, spawned with a geometry node set up that joins the selected objects into it but ignores it's original mesh
I want to spawn the cube on the active element, the cone in this case but I think I can do that by moving the cursor to the active

Hey, please clarify your question in more detail.

As I can understand, you might be looking for this
import bpy


# Create a new object
object_data = bpy.data.meshes.new("NewObject")
new_object = bpy.data.objects.new("NewObject", object_data)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(new_object)

# Create a new Geometry Nodes tree and modifier
node_tree = bpy.data.node_groups.new(name="NewGeometryNodesTree", type="GeometryNodeTree")
modifier = new_object.modifiers.new(name="Geometry Nodes", type="NODES")
modifier.node_group = node_tree

# Create group input and output nodes
group_input = node_tree.nodes.new("NodeGroupInput")
group_input.location.x = -500
group_output = node_tree.nodes.new("NodeGroupOutput")
group_output.location.x = 600

# Create input and output sockets
if bpy.app.version >= (4, 2, 0):
    node_tree.interface.new_socket("Geometry", description="", in_out="INPUT", socket_type="NodeSocketGeometry", parent=None)
    node_tree.interface.new_socket("Geometry", description="", in_out="OUTPUT", socket_type="NodeSocketGeometry", parent=None)
else:
    node_tree.inputs.new("NodeSocketGeometry", "Geometry")
    node_tree.outputs.new("NodeSocketGeometry", "Geometry")

# Create Join Geometry node
join_geo = node_tree.nodes.new("GeometryNodeJoinGeometry")
join_geo.location.x = 300

# Add Object Info nodes for selected objects
for i, obj in enumerate(bpy.context.selected_objects):
    if obj == new_object:
        continue
    node = node_tree.nodes.new("GeometryNodeObjectInfo")
    node.location = (-170 * (i % 2), i * 100)
    node.inputs["Object"].default_value = obj
    node.transform_space = "RELATIVE"
    node_tree.links.new(node.outputs["Geometry"], join_geo.inputs["Geometry"])

# Link nodes
node_tree.links.new(join_geo.outputs["Geometry"], group_output.inputs["Geometry"])


I need it to create the geometry nodes on a different, newly spawned object. This is bc the active object usually has a lot of modifiers on it so simply duplicating it is not enough, I need it to copy the final mesh.
(I've added pics to the questions to clarify)

ok, I changed the answer, let me know if it works as intended

Thanks a lot, not sure how but it works. I'll change the name of the question since it does what I want it too tho it's not about saving the selection
